# Only execute JS script on webpage if navigating there from an outside domain

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I have a small JS script that I would like to execute on my page but only if the user has navigated to that page from outside of our domain. If they navigate to said page from another page in the website's domain, the script shouldn't run. How can I accomplish this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the document.referrer property
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer

If this property is empty, the user went directly to your page.